# How to run examples from Symfony 6 Book "Symfony: The Fast Track"?

Tags: symfony, symfony6

I was on step "[Getting the Project Source Code](https://symfony.com/doc/6.2/the-fast-track/en/2-project.html#getting-the-project-source-code)" and ran:

`symfony new --version=6.2-1 --book guestbook`

**Problem:**
When 'symfony' folder is a parent forlder then I've got broken installation and wasn't able to checkout next steps, db doesn't work on port 5432 and so on. Something became broken all the time.
But when I just run this command in ~/projects then everything works.

**Solution:**
Path must not have 'symfony' in it.
I've found it by exident while collecting debug data for this report and installed in other folder.

Some errors I've got with wrong installation:

- Missing git tags.
- ERROR: for guestbook_blackfire_1 Cannot start service blackfire: cgroups: cgroup mountpoint does not exist: unknown
- Cannot start service blackfire: OCI runtime create failed: container with id exists: ...
- An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
  Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

```
docker-compose up -d
Building with native build. Learn about native build in Compose here: https://docs.docker.com/go/compose-native-build/
Starting guestbook_mailer_1    ... error
Starting guestbook_database_1 ... 
Starting guestbook_blackfire_1 ... 
Starting guestbook_database_1  ... error
ERROR: for guestbook_mailer_1  Cannot start service mailer: cgroups: cgroup mountpoint does not exist: unknown

Starting guestbook_blackfire_1 ... error

ERROR: for guestbook_blackfire_1  Cannot start service blackfire: cgroups: cgroup mountpoint does not exist: unknown

ERROR: for mailer  Cannot start service mailer: cgroups: cgroup mountpoint does not exist: unknown

ERROR: for database  Cannot start service database: cgroups: cgroup mountpoint does not exist: unknown

ERROR: for blackfire  Cannot start service blackfire: cgroups: cgroup mountpoint does not exist: unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

- I've removed Docker's container/images and recreated from scratch.
- Run this:

```
sudo mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
sudo mount -t cgroup -o none,name=systemd cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
```

- Multiple times did all steps from Symfony book up to step 8.
- Extracted git repo into other folder and manually moved .git/ folder and it's content to have git tags.
- Read a lot of SO topics and did a lot of other tries but without any success.